# How to highlight in Vim sequences of two symbols?

Tags: vim, highlight

For more comfortable work with YAML/Ansible I wanna highlight pairs of spaces with different colors in a row.

For example where we write `"      - name"` (six spaces here in the beginning of string) first pair of spaces will be yellow, next two will be red and so on.

But I can't understand how to write it in my .vimrc. Someone can help?

Comment: It sounds like you want something akin to an indent guide; is that correct?

Comment: Yes, indent with two-colors highlight of spaces, i think.

Answer (score 1):

These aren’t exactly the two-space highlighting your looking for, but [vim-indent-guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides) and [indentLine](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine) both can get you the essential feature of highlighting columns of indent.

The alternative I think would be to create `n` match groups where group `i` matches 2 spaces (after the first `2(i-1)` spaces), and then color those differently.